# How to sort eliminating some position in JS

Tags: javascript

I have an array as below.

```
const list = [ {key: 34}, {key: 17}, {key: 28}, {key: 35} ]
```

And I sort this depends on key value.

```
list.sort((a,b)=>{
      return a.key - b.key
    })
```

I got this.

```
const list = [ {key: 17}, {key: 28}, {key: 34}, {key: 35} ]
```

But after some function, the value is changed except first position. For, example:

```
const list = [ {key: 17}, {key: 31}, {key:  2}, {key: 26} ]
```

And I want to Sort this again except first position.
Therefore I want to get this result:

```
const list = [ {key: 17}, {key:  2}, {key: 26}, {key: 31} ]
```

And this procedure is repeated except first, second position until end.
How can I make a sort code for this situation ?

Comment: What is the meaning of "But after some function, the value is changed"

Comment: `list = list.slice(0, 1).concat( list.slice(1).sort(...) )`, and then `list = list.slice(0, 2).concat( list.slice(2).sort(...) )`, and so on

Comment: @PoojaKBhatt It means "after some operations that are irrelevant to the question, some values are changed"

Comment: As you are performing some operations on list like slice, concat etc. which changes elements in list, hence you have to perform sorting again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take the element who is not going to be taken into account in the sorting operation, then sort the array and insert the element in the specified index:

```js
const list = [{key:17},{key:31},{key:2},{key:26}]

function sortWithConstantIndex(arr, index = 0){
  arr = [...arr];
  const val = arr.splice(index, 1).pop();
  arr.sort(({key: aKey}, {key: bKey}) => +aKey - bKey);
  arr.splice(index, 0, val)
  return arr;
}

console.log(sortWithConstantIndex(list));
console.log(sortWithConstantIndex(list, 2));
console.log(sortWithConstantIndex(list, 1));
```

The example above doesn't mutate the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the array into 2 parts, one part that should be sorted, and one part that should remain in the same order as before. Then you concatenate the new sorted part onto the "old" unsorted part.

```js
const list = [{
    key: 17
  },
  {
    key: 31
  },
  {
    key: 2
  },
  {
    key: 26
  }
];

const sortFromIndex = (arr, index, compare) => arr
  .slice(0, index)
  .concat(arr
    .slice(index)
    .sort(compare)
  );

console.log(
  sortFromIndex(list, 1, (a, b) => a.key - b.key)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply propose:

```js
const list = [{key:17},{key:31},{key:2},{key:26}]

function sortFromIndex( i0, arr, sortFct )
  {
  let preserv = []
  while(i0--) preserv.push(arr.shift())
  arr.sort(sortFct).unshift(...preserv)
  }


sortFromIndex( 1, list, (a,b)=>a.key-b.key ) 

console.log( list )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

> You can also make it as a wrapper:

```js
// the wrapper: 
Array.prototype.sortFromIndex= function(i0, sortFct )
  {
  let preserv = []
  while(i0--) preserv.push(this.shift())
  this.sort(sortFct).unshift(...preserv)
  return this
  }
// ----------- end wrapper sortFromIndex

// test:

const list = [{key:17},{key:31},{key:2},{key:26}]

list.sortFromIndex(1,(a,b)=>a.key-b.key)

console.log( list )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to try **[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy)**  in that `_.orderBy` is useful. it's much simple to sort **arrayOfObject**

You have to use Like this `_.orderBy(chars, ['name'],['asc']);  //Use Lodash to sort array by 'name'`

In current Scenario here is the **key** so we have to use like this `_.orderBy(chars, ['key'],['asc']);`

[image: Result]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, post the actual code instead.